# 16 GB USB drive can only be used for 3.8 GB

Tags: usb, usb-storage

Recently I got a 16 GB USB Drive. But it allows only upto 3.78 GB. The rest are corrupted. Even formatting didn't help. I tried few utility tools. But still the same.

Is there any way that I could recover it, any tool or any suggestions please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you download [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) and look if there's a weird corrupted sets of partitions in your USB drive. It's highly recommended that you erase all the partitions from there. And format it with FAT32 (or whichever you like). Boot up your OS, and if it's Windows, it might ask you to reformat it, and yes do it.

Comment: My SD card have the same issue. Could GParted Live CD also recover data from the corrupted part?

Answer (score 2):

What is your drive format?  Windows FAT32 file system only allows files up to 4Gig in size.  Try reformat to NTFS.

Comment: That's the maximum *file* size for FAT32. The maximum volume size is 2 TB, which his drive is not hitting. The question doesn't read to me like a problem saving a particularly large file.

Answer (score 2):

Format the disk as NTFS, not FAT. As Cody mentioed above the maximum file size you can store on a FAT partition is ~4GB.